# How do I remove a mapping on all indices including .kibana and .marvel?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, kibana, elasticsearch-marvel

I am new to Elasticsearch for .NET (NEST) and didn't specify the index when adding a mapping.  Now the mapping exists on my indices for Kibana & Marvel.

How do I undo what I've done?  I'm using Elasticsearch 2.* and can't delete the mapping.  They say to just reindex, but I'm not sure how to do that for these indices.

```
  ".kibana": {
    "mappings": {
      "company": {
        "properties": {
          "iD": {
            "type": "double",
            "precision_step": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.

The only way to remove a mapping is to recreate the index without that mapping. The impact of that mapping (as goofy as it is) is low.